# Evaluate the series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

Let $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-\cos x}$$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=2$. If $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ is the Taylor expansion of $f$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n+1}$ is

(A) $0$

(B) $\frac{1}{2}$

(C) $1$

(D) $2$

Comment: Note $f$ is an even function.

Comment: @DavidMitra Please give one more hint.

Comment: Sigh... The Taylor expansion of an even function contains only even powers of $x$ (or, more precisely, all odd coefficients of the expansion are zero).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is an even function, i.e., $f(-x)=f(x)$, and hence all the odd order terms of its Taylor expansion are equal to $0$. Thus $\sum a_{2n+1}=0$.

Comment: Beautiful answer